# How to write regex to prevent passwords with consecutive characters?

Tags: regex

I have to check the validation of a password that must have at least 3 capital letters, 3 lower case letters, 2 digits, at least one of those characters (!@#$*), and the trickiest one it can not have the same character in a row. For example, "b**ee**r" is not allowed.

That's what I have done but it doesn't do a lot:

```
(?=[0-9]{2})&(?=[a-z]{3})&(?=[A-Z]{3})&(?=[!@#$*])&(?:(?!.([a-z]|[0-9]|[A-Z]|[!@#$*]{2})))
```

Comment: Is this homework or for a real task? If it's for a real task, don't try to do it all in one regex. Use multiple regexes.

Comment: Regardless if homework or real use case. Dont do that. Password complexity as security factor is bullshit. If you want to increase the security, go for length. Bigger is better ;) Dump this complexity insanity.

Comment: I fully agree with the above statement. Furthermore, such strange limitations only lessen the security. By forcing such rules on users you are driving users away and making their passwords less secure. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following pattern:

```
^(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){3})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){3})(?=(?:.*[0-9]){2})(?=.*[!@#$*])(?!.*(.)\1).*$
```

**[Demo](https://%5E(?=(?:.*%5BA-Z%5D)%7B3%7D)(?=(?:.*%5Ba-z%5D)%7B3%7D)(?=(?:.*%5B0-9%5D)%7B2%7D)(?=.*%5B!@#$*%5D)(?!.*(.)%5C1).*$)**.

**Breakdown:**

- `^` - Beginning of string.
- `(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){3})` - A positive Lookahead to assert at least 3 capital letters.
- `(?=(?:.*[a-z]){3})` - A positive Lookahead to assert at least 3 lowercase letters.
- `(?=(?:.*[0-9]){2})` - A positive Lookahead to assert at least 2 digits.
- `(?=.*[!@#$*])` - A positive Lookahead to assert at least one symbol.
- `(?!.*(.)\1)` - A negative Lookahead to reject the same character repeated twice in a row.
- `.*$` - Match zero or more characters until the end of the string.

Note: If you want to prevent the user from using any additional characters, you may replace the final `.*` part with:

```
[A-Za-z0-9!@#$*]*
```